# Stylus media query half working

Tags: css, media-queries, stylus

I have this media query, in the same file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 47.999em)
   // rest of css/stylus here

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em)
   // rest of css/stylus here
```

This works when I use my desktops chrome and under developer tools/settings/overrides change the device metrics.

But does **not work** on iPhone & Android.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

`xxx-device-width` should be - i was not using the word `device`.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 47.999em)
   // rest of css/stylus here

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 48em)
   // rest of css/stylus here
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 47.999em)
   // rest of css/stylus here

@media screen and (min-device-width: 48em)
   // rest of css/stylus here
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer sorry. I am using stylus, you are aware of that right?

Comment: Take the media values and put them in stylus.  Your problem is a media query problem, not a stylus problem.

Comment: Thank you again for looking at my problem. That did not solve it. I have been reading and found now the solution. Cheers!